# What should be values for initializing weights

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a model which consist of one covolutional layer,one average pooling and two fully connected layers. Where as the activation function is ReLu. But my final graphs are showing fluctuation. I want to minimize those fluctuations. I want to know that what values of mean and standard deviation in the following function will be helpful to minimze fluctuations? should it be large or small?

```
`def weight_variable(shape):
    initial= tf.truncated_normal(shape,mean=2,stddev=0.01)
    return tf.Variable(initial)`
```

Comment: generally, `mean` might be 0 or you can try `xavier initializer` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer. smaller `stddev` may help

Comment: there are no golden rule but rule of thumb. trial and error to reasonable solution.